# How to delete text in the file before and after some pattern

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a file with long words without spaces, many lines.

file.txt:

```
data-number="210615"
...
.... 
....
1280654445itemitemURLhttps://site.site.com/user-user/fooo/210615/file.name.jpg?1280654445name......
...
...
...
...
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash
find_number=$(grep -Po 'data-number="\K[^"]*' file.txt)

get-url= (copy from "https" to "fooo/" and add variable $find_number and add from "/" to end "jpg"
maybe : get-url=("https*,*fooo/",$find-number,"/*.jpg") this is work or other idea?

echo $get-url  > result.txt
```

result.txt:

```
https://site.site.com/user-user/fooo/210615/file.name.jpg
```

Comment: showing the lines you want to exclude is often just as important as showing the lines that contain the data you want.

Comment: Do you want to convert each `?` to a newline?

Comment: i want delete all (words,lines) before of http and delete all (words,lines) after of jpg.. keep that url correct, because i have many lines similar that url (different number data..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just stick with `grep` command as in number extraction:

```
grep -Po "http.*?$find_number.*?\.jpg"
```

Comment: your script is worked, i need other particular: if code is 'jpg' then "\.jpg", if code is png then "\.png"   how do i do? variable?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Quick-and-Dirty perl hack to extract the URLs that match a "data-number" line found earlier in the input.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $datanumber = 'stringthatwillneverbeintheinput';

while(<>) {
    chomp;
    if (m/^data-number/) {
        $datanumber = $_;
        $datanumber =~ s/^.*=|"//g;
    } elsif (m/$datanumber/) {
        s/^.*(http.*\.jpg).*/$1/;
        print "$_\n";
    }
}
```

Sample output from the input given above:

```
https://site.site.com/user-user/fooo/210615/file.name.jpg
```

Comment: where i will input file.txt ??

Comment: as you would with any other script  - save it to a file, make it exeutable with `chmod +x scriptname.pl`  and run it as `/path/to/scriptname.pl file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me the simplest solution and doesn't require setting any variables beforehand:

```
grep -oE "http.*$(grep data-number file.txt | cut -d'"' -f2).*\.jpg" file.txt
```

If you want to avoid the output that @manuel was referring to, just pipe it to `cut` to remove the query string like so:

```
grep -oE "http.*$(grep data-number file.txt | cut -d'"' -f2).*\.jpg" file.txt | cut -d? -f1
```

Comment: your command and result there is problem "?1280654445headerURL" see output:  https://site.site.com/user-user/fooo/210615/file.name1.jpg?1280654445itemURLhttps://site.site.com/user-user/fooo/210615/file.name2.jpg

Comment: @manuel I see what you're saying, but is that a realistic scenario? My command should work in 99% of cases.